# Using a variable into a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to insert the variable $src (it fetches the url of an image)

```
$src = $('a[class="button"]').attr("src");
```

into this string

```
$("a[class=panel]").append("--wanna insert $src here--");
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Not jQuery related. Basic JavaScript string concatenation. Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide

Comment: Why does your anchor have a `src` attribute? That's not valid according to [the standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#elements-1)

Answer (score 1):

```
var $src = $('a.button').attr("src");
```

and then:

```
$('div.panel').append('<div class="zoom-btn"><a href="' + $src + '"></a></div>');
```

or personally I would prefer:

```
$('div.panel').append(
    $('<div/>', {
        'class': 'zoom-btn'
    }).append('<a/>', {
        href: $src
    })
);
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, the first I would prefer the first choice tough is much more readable to me ( and resembles php as well). Nice and clean idea. Now I would like to scan all the a.button links in the page ( I assume I need to use each() and for each $src fetched to display the structure in the div.panel. I tried but I got not luck. Could you help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**This answer isn't relevant now you've gone and completely changed the question after you've posted..**

```
var src = $('a[class="button"]').attr("src");
$("div[class=panel]").append(src);
```

Comment: or a one-liner `$("div[class=panel]").append($('a[class="button"]').attr("src"));`

Answer (score -1):

You mentioned in your question that you want to insert variable $src which fetch the Url of an Image.
and for Image we need

```
$src = $('a[class="button"] img').attr("src","<?=$src?>");
```

Anchor with "button" class containing image tag

```
<a href="#" class="button"><img src=""/></a>
```

and you can also use below code if you don't have  element inside anchor.

```
$src = $('a[class="button"]').append('<img src="<?=$src?>"/>');
```